# Xcode 8 Messages Template Application: Error on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, message

When I create a new project using the "Messages Application" template of Xcode 8 and try to run it on iOS simulator, I get the following error:

### Title

> The request to open `com.myDomain.MyApp` failed.

### Details

> The request was denied by service delegate (`SBMainWorkspace`) for reason: `NotFound ("Application "com.myDomain.MyApp" is unknown to FrontBoard").`

The message is the same for `Objective-C` and `Swift` projects.

I don't find any search result for this message yet, so any hint will be helpful. I will update the question as I progress.

### Edit

This error occurred with Xcode 8 beta versions.

Comment: @Vikrant: thanks for editing, but the new formatting treats the error description as code and that makes it harder to read. I edited it again to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: did you check your scheme? Edit Scheme -> Info -> executable should be set to ask on launch rather than MyApp.app

Comment: Thanks a lot, that made it work! I still had to wait until the simulator fully launched (very slow, took a few minutes), but that's it.

Comment: What did you help? Just turn on 'Wait executable for launch'?

Comment: @Misha: Yes, I checked the setting and found that the executable was set to the target called <appName>.app instead of the extension. ubiAle posted this as an answer, so I accepted it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to check your scheme. The executable should be asked on launch (You want to select Messages app). 
Edit Scheme -> Info -> Executable -> Ask on launch (rather than MyApp.app)

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem，then i fixed it by two steps:

1. click the `New Scheme`, add a new scheme.
2. click the `Manage Schemes`, and delete the old.

then (Although I don't know why) I can run my project!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I was using a beta of xcode 8.1. When I upgraded the app store version of xcode from 8.0 to 8.1 this problem disappeared (and it never happened with 8.0, just the 8.1 beta). Couldn't find a reference to a bug or a fix, but if you're not using the official app store version of xcode it might be worth double checking.

Comment: Good point; I posted the question when I was using the beta version. It never happened after installing the App Store version. Will see if I can update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I had an empty environment variable set in my current scheme.

[image: Environment variables]

I deleted this empty environment variable and was then able to build correctly.