# react-native run-ios doesn't run: Application is unknown to FrontBoard?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I had `react-native run-ios` working for the past few days but today it randomly decided to stop working:

---

```
The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    Analyze /Users/swyx/Desktop/webdev/fullstacksr/reactNativeExtensions/ActionExtensionExample3/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c
    Analyze /Users/swyx/Desktop/webdev/fullstacksr/reactNativeExtensions/ActionExtensionExample3/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.c
(2 commands with analyzer issues)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ActionExtensionExample3.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to set plugin placeholders for org.reactjs.native.example.ShareExtensionExampleswyx
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.ShareExtensionExampleswyx
org.reactjs.native.example.ShareExtensionExampleswyx: -1
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "org.reactjs.native.example.ShareExtensionExampleswyx" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application "org.reactjs.native.example.ShareExtensionExampleswyx" is unknown to FrontBoard").
```

---

Possible causes and solutions investigated:

- [Checking the scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939749/xcode-8-messages-template-application-error-on-ios-simulator) - it is definitely `Ask on launch`
- [Scheme settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645824/the-request-was-denied-by-service-delegate-sbmainworkspace) - i dont have any empty settings to leave unchecked
- Maximum App ID limit reached - this app id `org.reactjs.native.example.ShareExtensionExampleswyx` is something I am reusing but i dont think it causes this issue
- deleting `ios/build` and recompiling
- restarting my simulator and my entire computer
- Edit: yes i am using xcode 9

none of these have worked so far. Any other ideas on things to try please?

Comment: maybe unlink this share extension package?

Comment: thanks for the reply - the share extension was created from within XCode so I never linked it (from RN) in the first place. in any case, I am trying to keep it as that is a key part of the project. also worth mentioning that I get this error when creating a completely new `ignite` project.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try with another simulator if it works you need to  reset your simulator from simulator menu

1. Simulator -> Reset Content And Setting if you have Xcode 9 it will be from Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings
2. clean from Xcode menu Product -> Clean and run your project

Comment: i actually solved by creating a brand new apple ID as i think there was a bundle identifier conflict but this solution might have done it too. no idea. marking correct because was a reasonable new answer i had not yet foudn in my research

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned by Gavin Owens on Github, I followed those steps and it worked.

Just delete **ios/build from iOS directory and after that run command react-native-run-ios**

use following command

**rm -rf ios/build then running react-native run-ios**